# Kubuntu - Upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 fails no mouse no keyboard

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, kubuntu, mouse

After doing the "do-release-upgrade" my laptop (Thinkpad T460 )wasn't starting correctly anymore. The mouse appeared during boot up, but did not move. When the login screen of Kubuntu appeared, I could not login in because the keystrokes weren't accepted (looked as if there was no keyboard at all). I could boot into recovery but hat no network there (even after starting it from the friendly console).

External Keyboard and mouse were not working after boot, but worked similar to the built in keyboard in recovery mode.

After two days of playing around in the recovery I finally found the problem.

Some component were looking for libffi.so.6 but it has been replaced by libffi.so.7.1.0. Setting up a symbolic link to the v7 fixed the broken laptop for me, it is now running normal.

How can I find out which program refers to this old lib? I found the reference in the logs when trying to start network-manager in recovery, but I was not able to determine what program really failed.

Comment: The component was network-manager, I assume...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran in the same problem when upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 and it was libffi again.

Here are some steps I took that may help others. If you are not careful you can of course finally ruin your system, so backing up before is good practice (although it may be painful without network).

When the system halts during boot and shows failed services such as thermal daemon, network-manager or others.

Boot the recovery kernel (hold shift after the boot logo/bios messages), choose "Boot options" and take the second line in the list which is the recovery of the new kernel. This normally has always worked to get a menu where you can start a root shell.

Check your init ram disk. I once had the problem that from 18.04 to 20.04 on my desktop the initrd was empty (0 bytes). You'll find a lot of hints here how to rebuild that that it fits to your installation.

Check `/var/log/syslog` for entries that point to a failed dynamic library with `grep "error while loading`

If that's the case look for a similar named lib in `/usr/lib` or `/lib` with `cd /lib;find . -iname "*libxxx*" -print` with xxx being the name of the missing lib

Make a symbolic link from the exisiting lib to the missing lib. In my case here it was `ln -s libffi.so.8.1.0 libffi.so.6`. I still need advice what you think is the better way here. The described link new for old or get the old lib from the network and copy it alongside the new one.

Repeat if there are more than one, then reboot

Your're system should now boot regularly. I then had the problem that plasma was crashing and a lot of programs did not start but complain about a missing symbol in a shared library. That's a version mismatch for the library, the program loads the outdated lib and fails to find the symbols it is looking for. Of course all the other hints like `sudo apt install --fix-broken` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` should be considered as well.

I use libpango now for the example, check your error message.

I tried to start `filezilla`

The error message looks like `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_memdup2`

The symbol is not missing in libpango but in a lib that libpango tries to load. Your friend is `ldd` here.

Enter `ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0`

In the following list look for libs in `/usr/local/lib`, this was the problem for me now several times. Move these usr-local-libs away. In my case there was a outdated glib (no idea where it came from) `sudo mv libglib-2.0.so* /tmp/oldlibs`.

Repeat that for every error that ocurs.

I don't know if I'm especially unlucky but that's the second upgrade that failed in the first place because of libffi...any hints on that?